# Systematically replace namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, refactoring

SO I have a HUGE C#/ASP.NET application that is now getting re-appropriated for other projects. I would like to change our project specific namespaces to something more generic.

Using the right-click refactor on the namespace name only globally changes imports for that specific file. This will be a huge ordeal by hand. Is there a better way to do it than just carefully done find and replace?

Also, we use codebehinds so front-facing aspx pages will also have to change their imported namespaces.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Read.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectSpecificNamespace.Read" %>
```

and of course the cs file imports and any references in inline code pages will also have to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ReSharper you can change a folder name, and then "Adjust Namespaces" - if you want to change the default namespace of an entire assembly, you can edit that setting in the project properties, and *then* adjust namespaces.  You can adjust all namespaces in an entire solution with one click this way.